# Kubernetes with Linux WSL on Windows 11

Tags: linux, mongodb, kubernetes, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have Windows 11 with WSL2 and Ubuntu installed, but from Windows I can't access all the IP generated into the Linux WSL.

Case: in Linux WSL I deployed with Kubernetes Minikube (virtualized with KVM2)a simple cluster with 2 nodes, MongoDb, and Mongo Express. When I launch `minikube dashboard`, it launches it on `http://127.0.0.1:XXXXX` and from Windows Chrome works.

But when I launch `minikube service mongodb-express-service` to expose the address it launches it on `http://192.168.39.253:30000` and looks ok, but I can't reach it from Windows.
If I ping it doesn't respond.

I tried a lot of solutions (firewall, different ips, ...a lot!!) that I found but nothing seems like working...

Is it possible or WSL is "limited"?

Does someone experience it?

Does someone have found a solution?

This is not regarding specifically Kubernetes but my question is more general if I would like to deploy something else.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide more details on your installation method ("virtualized with KVM2")?  I've been experimenting a bit with `libvirt` under WSL2, but yes, networking is one of the challenges I'm facing.  Is there a particular installation guide that you followed for minikube kvm2 under WSL2?  My understanding is that the typical WSL2 Kubernetes installation makes use of Docker?

Comment: pretty simple configuration with `minikube start --vm-driver=kvm2` then  `libvirt` creates the bridges `virbr0` and `virbr1` with the addresses `192.168.39.x` used minikubes.
If I edit the net with `virsh net-edit mk-minikube` changing the address, `minikube` does not work anymore

Comment: not the answer but you can use linux browser in windows 11 wsl to access your container.

Comment: Thanks. I tried also that but didn't work. Maybe I stumbled upon the wrong solution. Do you have any links? It could be useful